# Flutter passing data to children widgets

Tags: flutter

Passing data from parent to child can be messy the more widgets are used, child to a child to a child.
Is there a way to use the data of the first father without keep passing it, provider is used to pass data between widgets on the same level, between screens, but i mean cases there is many children for one screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FirstFather extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstFather({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Child(
      prop: "exmaple",
    );
  }
}

class Child extends StatelessWidget {
  final String prop;
  const Child({Key key, this.prop}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Grandson(
        prop: prop,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Grandson extends StatelessWidget {
  final String prop;
  const Grandson({Key key, this.prop}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(prop),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please describe more or show an example.

Comment: I added example

Answer (score 0):

Use InheritedWidget:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html

When you put it at the top of your Widget tree, all the children can access the data.

Comment: its not the same as using provider?

Comment: Watch the Video and you will understand.